# Реализовать покупку в приложении через Google Play

Tags: android

Хочу реализовать в приложении покупку, чтобы отключилась реклама. Нашла код на гитхаб и реализовала для своего примера. Но после оплаты:

1. В консоли разработчика висит что платеж не Оплачен несколько минут, затем меняется на Оплачен. Через In-App Billing вроде сразу оплачивался
2. Когда второй раз в приложении нажимаю купить пишет что платеж отклонен (если денег не хватает) и повторно разрешает купить, если на счету есть. Почему так?

IAPHelper.class

```
public class IAPHelper {

    private String TAG = IAPHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context;
    private BillingClient mBillingClient;
    private IAPHelperListener IAPHelperListener;
    private List<String> skuList;

    /**
     * To instantiate the object
     *  @param context           It will be used to get an application context to bind to the in-app billing service.
     * @param IAPHelperListener Your listener to get the response for your query.
     * @param skuList
     */
    public IAPHelper(Context context, IAPHelperListener IAPHelperListener, List<String> skuList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.IAPHelperListener = IAPHelperListener;
        this.skuList = skuList;
        this.mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(getPurchaseUpdatedListener())
                .build();
        if (!mBillingClient.isReady()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "BillingClient: Start connection...");
            startConnection();
        }
    }

    /**
     * To establish the connection with play library
     * It will be used to notify that setup is complete and the billing
     * client is ready. You can query whatever you want.
     */
    private void startConnection() {
        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                int billingResponseCode = billingResult.getResponseCode();
                Log.d(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());
                if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    getPurchasedItems();
                    getSKUDetails(skuList);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected: ");
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get purchases details for all the items bought within your app.
     */
    public void getPurchasedItems() {
        Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        if (IAPHelperListener != null)
            IAPHelperListener.onPurchasehistoryResponse(purchasesResult.getPurchasesList());
    }

    /**
     * Perform a network query to get SKU details and return the result asynchronously.
     */
    public void getSKUDetails(List<String> skuList) {
        final HashMap<String, SkuDetails> skuDetailsHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        SkuDetailsParams skuParams = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP).setSkusList(skuList).build();
        mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuParams, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                    for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                        skuDetailsHashMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
                    }
                    if (IAPHelperListener != null)
                        IAPHelperListener.onSkuListResponse(skuDetailsHashMap);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Initiate the billing flow for an in-app purchase or subscription.
     *
     * @param skuDetails skudetails of the product to be purchased
     *                   Developer console.
     */
    public void launchBillingFLow(final SkuDetails skuDetails) {
        if(mBillingClient.isReady()){
            BillingFlowParams mBillingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                    .build();
            mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow((Activity) context, mBillingFlowParams);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Your listener to get the response for purchase updates which happen when, the user buys
     * something within the app or by initiating a purchase from Google Play Store.
     */
    private PurchasesUpdatedListener getPurchaseUpdatedListener() {
        return (billingResult, purchases) -> {
            int responseCode = billingResult.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
                //here when purchase completed
                for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                    //I have named sku in such a way that I get sku name as "type_name" for ex: "nc_ring"
                    //For non consumable I will acknowledge purchase
                    //For consumable I will consume purchase
                    String type = purchase.getSku().split("_")[0];
                    if(type.equals("nc"))
                        acknowledgePurchase(purchase);
                    else
                        consumePurchase(purchase);
                }
            } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
                // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
                Log.d(TAG, "user cancelled");
            } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Log.d(TAG , "service disconnected");
                startConnection();
            }
        };
    }

    public void acknowledgePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED
                && isSignatureValid(purchase)) {

            //This is for Consumable product
            AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                    .build();
            mBillingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
                    Log.d("purchase", "Purchase Acknowledged");
                }
            });

            if (IAPHelperListener != null)
                IAPHelperListener.onPurchaseCompleted(purchase);
        }
    }

    public void consumePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED
                && isSignatureValid(purchase)) {

            //This is for Consumable product
            ConsumeParams consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                    .build();
            mBillingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, new ConsumeResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult billingResult, String s) {
                    Log.d("purchase", "Purchase Consumed");
                }
            });

            if (IAPHelperListener != null)
                IAPHelperListener.onPurchaseCompleted(purchase);
        }
    }

    private boolean isSignatureValid(Purchase purchase) {
        return Security.verifyPurchase(Security.BASE_64_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY, purchase.getOriginalJson(), purchase.getSignature());
    }

    /**
     * Call this method once you are done with this BillingClient reference.
     */
    public void endConnection() {
        if (mBillingClient != null && mBillingClient.isReady()) {
            mBillingClient.endConnection();
            mBillingClient = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Listener interface for handling the various responses of the Purchase helper util
     */
    public interface IAPHelperListener {
        void onSkuListResponse(HashMap<String, SkuDetails> skuDetailsHashMap);
        void onPurchasehistoryResponse(List<Purchase> purchasedItem);
        void onPurchaseCompleted(Purchase purchase);
    }


}
```

Security.class

```
public class Security {
    private static final String TAG = Security.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
    private static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA1withRSA";

    //This you will get from Services & API in your application console
    public static String BASE_64_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY = "MyKEY";

    /**
     * Verifies that the data was signed with the given signature, and returns
     * the verified purchase. The data is in JSON format and signed
     * with a private key. The data also contains the {@link Purchase.PurchaseState}
     * and product ID of the purchase.
     * @param base64PublicKey the base64-encoded public key to use for verifying.
     * @param signedData the signed JSON string (signed, not encrypted)
     * @param signature the signature for the data, signed with the private key
     */
    public static boolean verifyPurchase(String base64PublicKey, String signedData, String signature) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(signedData) || TextUtils.isEmpty(base64PublicKey) ||
                TextUtils.isEmpty(signature)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Purchase verification failed: missing data.");
            return false;
        }

        PublicKey key = Security.generatePublicKey(base64PublicKey);
        return Security.verify(key, signedData, signature);
    }

    /**
     * Generates a PublicKey instance from a string containing the
     * Base64-encoded public key.
     *
     * @param encodedPublicKey Base64-encoded public key
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if encodedPublicKey is invalid
     */
    private static PublicKey generatePublicKey(String encodedPublicKey) {
        try {
            byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
            return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key specification.");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verifies that the signature from the server matches the computed
     * signature on the data.  Returns true if the data is correctly signed.
     *
     * @param publicKey public key associated with the developer account
     * @param signedData signed data from server
     * @param signature server signature
     * @return true if the data and signature match
     */
    private static boolean verify(PublicKey publicKey, String signedData, String signature) {
        byte[] signatureBytes;
        try {
            signatureBytes = Base64.decode(signature, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Base64 decoding failed.");
            return false;
        }
        try {
            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
            sig.initVerify(publicKey);
            sig.update(signedData.getBytes());
            if (!sig.verify(signatureBytes)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Signature verification failed.");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "NoSuchAlgorithmException.");
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key specification.");
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Signature exception.");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

About.class

```
public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, IAPHelper.IAPHelperListener{

    private BillingClient mBillingClient;

    IAPHelper iapHelper;
    HashMap<String, SkuDetails> skuDetailsHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    final String PAY = "tovar";
    private List<String> skuList = Arrays.asList(PAY);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ***

        iapHelper = new IAPHelper(this, this, skuList);




    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Button radio = findViewById(R.id.PAY);

        radio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launch(PAY);
            }
        });
    }

    private void launch(String sku){
        if(!skuDetailsHashMap.isEmpty())
            iapHelper.launchBillingFLow(skuDetailsHashMap.get(sku));
    }


    @Override
    public void onSkuListResponse(HashMap<String, SkuDetails> skuDetails) {
        skuDetailsHashMap = skuDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchasehistoryResponse(List<Purchase> purchasedItems) {
        if (purchasedItems != null) {
            for (Purchase purchase : purchasedItems) {
                //Update UI and backend according to purchased items if required
                // Like in this project I am updating UI for purchased items
                //Если товар купен уже
                String sku = purchase.getSku();
                switch (sku) {
                    case PAY:
                        System.out.println("PAY");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseCompleted(Purchase purchase) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Purchase Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePurchase(purchase);
    }

    private void updatePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        String sku = purchase.getSku();
        switch (sku) {
            case PAY:
                System.out.println("PAY");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (iapHelper != null) {
            iapHelper.endConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде, все покупки, которые не начинаются с `nc_` считаются `consumable` и, соответственно, доступны для последующей покупки. Вам надо или создать новый продукт или изменить соответственно код.

Comment: А что именно нужно переделать в коде? В условии прописать название своего товара?

Comment: Это очень сильно зависит от того что именно и как вам нужно. Наверное, подойдёт оставление `acknowledgePurchase(purchase);` и убирание всего остального из цикла в PurchasesUpdatedListener

Comment: На данный момент у меня только один товар (отключение межстраничной рекламы) и называется он tovar (название могу поменять, но пока так). Так вот нужно, чтобы при его покупке пользователь не смог повторно его купить.

Comment: В предыдущем комментарии я написал что нужно сделать в таком случае.

Comment: Да, сейчас как раз пытаюсь реализовать. Спасибо. Единственное у меня вопрос. Описанный выше код удовлетворяет google pay billing версии 3? Или там что-то поменялось?

Comment: Должно работать, по идее, если версия либы - последняя.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но возник вопрос. В классе IAHelper есть метод getPurchasedItems(), который возвращает покупки пользователя. Добавила в него кусок         for (Purchase p : purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()) {
            System.out.println(p.getSku());
        }, чтобы видеть покупки пользователя. Но среди них нет покупки товара tovar. Почему так?

Comment: Сложно сказать. Либо оно не показывает потреблённые ранее покупки, либо вы нужную только недавно сделали и она ещё не закешировалась. Попробуйте использовать другой метод получения покупок, который не использует кэш. Или почистите кэш (и приложения и PlayMarket). Возможно, очистки кэша будет не достаточно и надо сбросить все данные, после чего перелогиниться в магазине.

Comment: А каким еще методом я могу получить купленные товары? Извиняюсь что достаю конечно. В документации был описан метод queryPurchases, он используется в коде у меня. Другого не знаю.

Comment: Вот таким `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync`: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#querypurchasehistoryasync

Comment: Спасибо попробую.

Comment: Последний вопрос остался. В консоли разработчика вернула платеж для аккаунта, но в методе onPurchasehistoryResponse класса About срабатывает строка System.out.println("PAY"); Если я правильно понимаю, то при возврате платежа товар уже не принадлежит пользователю и не должен этот код срабаывать. Но почему у меня Выводит PAY. Будто товар все еще куплен?

Comment: Чистила кеш приложения и маркета. Не помогло

Comment: То что вы описываете - похоже на проблему кэша. Возможно, вы почистили кэш приложений, но не почистили все данные. Попробуйте все данные почистить, не только кэш. Только кэш чистить почти всегда - бесполезно. Также, указанный вами метод данные из кэша как раз берёт, лучше используйте ранее помянутый метод, который кэш не использует.

Comment: Я читала что выше упомянутый метод покажет только последнюю покупку, причем даже если она отменена. Может я и ошибаюсь конечно. А на счет кеша я делала очистить кеш и очистить все, но что-то не помогло. Попробую разобраться еще.

Comment: Вы в логи выводите факт наличия в списке вашей покупки, но не её состояние. Судя по доке, специального состояния там нет, однако, возможно, оно в `getPurchaseState()` как-то обозначено? Какое там у вас значение?

Comment: getPurchaseState() возвращает 1. Если я правильно понимаю это означает что покупка отменена.

Comment: В классе IAPHelper есть метод getPurchasedItems. Он ведь выводит список тех покупок, которые есть у пользователя. Т.е. если пользователь запросил возврат или каким-то образом покупка была отменена, то в этот метод не должен попадать товар, который был отменен.

Comment: Судя по доке, статус - оплачено. Проверьте, что вы не путаете разные покупки. У вас были они сначала потребляемыми, теперь нет. Возможно, вам возвращается  последняя ранее употреблённая покупка, а не та, что вы отменили. Проверьте это путём вывода, например, `getOrderId()` и сравнения его значения с отменённой покупкой.

Comment: Проверила.. идентификатор заказа выводится тот же что я вижу в консоли как отмененный (Платеж возвращен). Может где-то в коде ошибка у меня, только не могу понять где и какая ошибка.

Comment: Других идей у меня нет. Должно работать.